# two case statements for the same column in insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my plsql procedure, I am inserting rows based on the values of some other rows of the same table.  For one column inside the insert statement I need to manipulate the existing row value based on case statement and then insert. What I do is:

I create a curser to the existing row to be used and then use its column values.

```
 INSERT into table columns
 (column names..)
 values (
 curser.column names
 ,case 
     when input is null then null 
     else input||'.'|| 
 end 
 case 
     when curser.column like 'drop:%' then replace(curser.column,'drop:%') 
     else curser.column 
 end
 , other column values).
```

Here input is an argument of my procedure.

Both the case statements are for the same column value. (Both the statemtents together completes the value for that column) 
But I am getting error for the second 'case' statement. 
Is this not correct?

Comment: You're missing a comma but as this is isn't the code you're actually running it's hard to tell if that's just a problem you've introduced writing the question. Saying "I am getting error" isn't very helpful; *what* error?

Comment: exactly that's the problem. but I cant put a comma there right? because both the case statements are for the same column value. If I put a comma it will considered as the next column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> input||'.'|| end case
> ```

That section is syntactically not OK. There's no second operand to the second string concatenation and no comma (or other operator) after `end`.

You presumably want to replace it with

```
input||'.' end || case
```

to concatenate the results of both `CASE`s.

If there are other problems, like the number of target columns not matching the number of values, is hard to tell as there is too much left out.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an operation for a cursor.  I would expect `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t columns (column names..)
    select . . .,
           (case when t.input is not null then input || '.' end),
           replace(t.column, 'drop:', ''),
           . . .
    from t
    where . . . ;
```